# Slickgrid - want to load options in dropdown cell 2, based on selected value in dropdown cell 1(Think state and city on same row)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

1. I have a slickgrid.
2. Two of the columns in my grid, happen to be dropdown lists. I use selectCellEditor on those columns.
3. one column in like "State" field and another is like "City" field, for example.
   When the user selects a specific "State" from state column's dropdown list, would like the options under "City" column to be dynamically uploaded. All the data is already available in a javascript object already fetched from database (That's cheaper for me).
4. I am using the grid.onCellChange(..) and I know the new state value chosen by the user.
5. **But, how to use this information to load the relevant city values ? Earlier versions of slickgrid seem to have had a "SetValueHandler" option for "columns". But, I am not finding the same in the latest version.**

To be more precise, as an example,

- In Row 8 of the grid, when someone changes state from
  "California(CA)" to "New York(NY)", and then click on the "City" cell
  in the same row 8, I would like to have the dropdown to be populated
  with all the cities in the state of New York.
- I have the data available already as obj['New York'] = ["NYC",...] and can access it.
- I am not very sure, using OnCellChange is the way to go

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.